# Why won't this specific function work?

Tags: javascript

Create a function called whichChild that takes one parameter: a child's name.
When passed in ‘Dave’ return ‘Oldest’
When passed in ‘Michelle’ return ‘Middle’
When given any other value return ‘Not my kid!”

```js
function whichChild(achildsname){
  var name = prompt ("Which Child?");
  
  if (name == "Dave") {
    prompt("Oldest");
  }
  else if (name == "Michelle"){
    prompt("Middle");
  }
  else (name /= "Dave" && "Michelle"){
    prompt("Not My Kid!");
  }
}
```

Ok redo! How am I supposed to make this function take one parameter? I need it to take one parameter: a child's name. Im supposed to create this function for a test. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

```
function whichChild(){
  var name = prompt("Which Child?");

  if (name === "Dave") {
    console.log("Oldest");
  }
  else if (name === "Michelle"){
    console.log("Middle");
  }
  else {
    console.log("Not My Kid!");
  }
}
```

whichChild();

You don't need the parameter, because there is no need of calling an argument in the function. Instead of prompt, use console.log, I assume you are trying to display a message after the user has prompted a name, so, it would not be appropriate to have a prompt after another prompt, when the only thing you need is a response,"whichChild();" will invoke that function.

Comment: is there a way to make this function take one parameter?

Comment: Yes you can, but you are not using it, so you don't have to put a parameter, even though you can, I would advice not too, its just not needed.

Comment: what parameter could I use? Sorry to ask questions I am just new to this.

Comment: I've edited the post if you could take a quick look that would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want:

```js
function whichChild() {
    var name = prompt("Which Child?");
    
    if (name == "Dave") {
        alert("Oldest");
    } else if (name == "Michelle") {
        alert("Middle");
    } else {
        alert("Not My Kid!");
    }
}

whichChild();
```